# blank page with domain name inside

Tags: nginx, webserver, fail2ban, ufw

I set up a server on Ubuntu 20.04, installed and configured UFW and fail2ban, installed nginx, opened 80 and 443 ports. Created a config file for my domain and started the server. It works, but from my IP address (from which I set up the server), I cannot get to the site. When I request a domain, I get a white page on which my domain is written in plain text. But as soon as I register the domain and IP in the hosts file, the site becomes available. I see the problem only from my IP, from others - the site is available. I can provide server settings, but they are corny simple. The site is still pure HTML. Even php didn't install.

Help me find the problem, or at least a direction to fix it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It might be related to cached DNS queries. Remove the entry from `/etc/hosts` file and restart your local machine.